# How to switch writing direction from right to left in Mac apps?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editing, right-to-left

### Writing in right-to-left languages on Mac apps

I need to write in a **right-to-left** language, on my Mac computer. On my Windows computer, I used to press <kbd>Control (⌃)</kbd> + <kbd>Right Shift (⇧)</kbd> to switch the writing direction. I learned that there is a similar shortcut on Mac: <kbd>Control (⌃)</kbd> + <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow (←)</kbd>. I also tried <kbd>Control (⌃)</kbd> + <kbd>Option (⌥)</kbd> + <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow (←)</kbd>, but neither of them works in most apps except for Microsoft Word.

Is there a way to switch the writing direction from right to left in Mac apps that do not support these shortcuts? I checked the Format menu in some apps, but I did not find any option for writing directions.

I often write in Hebrew, a right-to-left language. However, I've encountered an issue where the keyboard shortcut for right-to-left typing isn’t functioning in most applications, even though it is displayed in the settings when I add the RTL language.

Below is a screenshot illustrating this issue:
[image: Issue Screenshot]

Here’s another screenshot showing the menu settings and hotkeys designated for changing text direction:
[image: Text Direction Hotkeys Menu]

Apple's [documentation](https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/guide/mac-help/mh21243/mac#:%7E:text=Change%20selected%20text%20to%20right,Control%2DCommand%2DRight%20Arrow.) of those hotkeys:
[https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/guide/mac-help/mh21243/mac#:~:text=Change%20selected%20text%20to%20right,Control%2DCommand%2DRight%20Arrow.](https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/guide/mac-help/mh21243/mac#:%7E:text=Change%20selected%20text%20to%20right,Control%2DCommand%2DRight%20Arrow.)

Comment: What language are writing in? Usually that would be changed system wide in “System Settings > Keyboard” or something like that. More info can be [found here](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/write-in-another-language-on-mac-mchlp1406/mac). Try it out!

Comment: I write in Hebrew, which is a right-to-left language. However, I've encountered a problem where the right-to-left keyboard shortcut, which is displayed in the settings when I add the RTL language, is not functioning in most applications.

Below is a screenshot illustrating the issue:
https://i.imgur.com/Y4lqZPC.png

Comment: I see the screenshot, but it is not obvious to men what the issue is. I have added the comment (and screenshot) to your question since it is good additional information.

Comment: When I press the Command + Control + Left Arrow it should change the text direction from right to left.

Comment: Makes sense. Hopefully someone will have an answer.

Comment: You can switch the text direction from right to left on Apple Pages by pressing Command + Control + Left Arrow.

However, this keyboard shortcut does not work on most other apps or websites.

Comment: Is is possible these apps simply do not support this function? I would guess that in order to support left to right writing web pages or applications need to support specific input fields or APIs or methods, and this isn't included in every application or page.

Comment: In Windows, all applications supported Right To Left input, especially websites on Chrome or Edge.

So I wondered if it was an OS-specific problem.